# SPSS data weighted but not weighted when loaded in R

Tags: r, dataset, spss, weighted

I received a dataset of weighted data exported from SPSS that I want to analyze in R. When I loaded the data into R, I realized that the weights were not preserved and I'm looking at the raw data. Is there something I can do so that the weights are preserved?

Answer (score 1):

The data in SPSS is not weighted either - when you run `weight by SomeVar.` in SPSS, you are telling SPSS to use the weights in all the calculations and analyses, but the data is not changed. When you load the data into R you have the same raw data you had in SPSS, and you have to tell R to use weighting in your calculations and analyses.